# Exporting variables to siblings elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im creating simple test React app.

I've got a small database filled with JS objects. When user types query into a searchbar and presses enter i export this.state.form (string from searchbar) to a variable. Then I iterate through database and if I find a record's name equal to form variable I want to display the details of this object in a div.

However, this div component is in another, sibling JS file and I cant figure out how to effectively export variables and their values to sibling files without Redux.

With pseudo code it would be something like this:

```
var isFound;
var arrayNumber;

// I iterate through the array of objects with for loop to find correct object and store "i" to arrayNumber and want to export it
// If record is found i set isFound to true, otherwise to false
```

In a new file I render a simple div, where I want to do the following

```
//if isFound is false
<div>Not found</div>
//if found
<div>database[i].details</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create parent components for these 2 components. 
For example, now your structure is smth like

```
<Component>
  <Subcomponent />
  <Subcomponent />
  ... other content
</Component>
```

You should change it to

```
<Component>
  <ParentSubcomponent>
    <Subcomponent />
    <Subcomponent />
  </ParentSubcomponent>
  ... other content
</Component>
```

And leave to `ParentComponent` to handle search & display using callbacks for `Subcomponents` (change `ParentComponent's` state on `Subcomponent` onClick on search button, that will rerender second `Subcomponent` because of provided props, that are get from `ParentComponent's` state (actually it's search result), have been changed, so save data about search & display info in `ParentSubcomponent's` state.

So single source of truth will be `ParentSubcomponent's` state, 1st `Subcomponent` uses callback to update it with the search result, 2nd `Subcomponent` gets search result (from state) as a props and updates itself.

Comment: Seems confusing and generates a lot of additional code. I wish we could just export it and import just like we import files. I'll try to rebuild the app, but now I wish I wassnt stubborn and sticked with pure react